Angular signals-template "null-check and assign" also works in Typescript?
In angular I can use signals in templates like this (user is a signal):
@if (user(); as user) { <!-- ✅  -->
    <p>{{ user.name }}</p>
}

Now I'm curious if the typescript also allows me to "check and assign" in one go for regular variables:
if(this.myService.someFn(); as myReturnValue) { // ⛔
   // do something with myReturnValue
}

Is there a possiblity to do null-check and assign in one go within in if-condition in typescript?
-Edit-
Because there was some misunderstanding what I want. I want this example to work:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/FASwZgFAzg9gtgUwGIDsIEoDcACAhlbOATwCUEAXAVwCcUA1XAG0oXWwG9thseB6X7ABMY2WInIALECgDm2AO4hJhUhRr0mLYAF9gwMJRQBjciBgpR8ZGnQAubCkpwARgmoduPbNTW1sAWVxJADowRhgYaghAkOpcFGE4DGwAKmwARgAGLB0gA

There is not directly a way in Javascript or Typescript like in Angulars new control flow.
But you can do it like this:
let value: any;

if(value = someFn()) { 
   // do something with myReturnValue
   console.log(value);
}

function someFn(): number {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
}

Ultimately, this is the normal way to use it, but if your function doesn't always return a value (so it can return false or null, for example), you can declare a value in your class to use it "globally" so to speak, and you can make your code a little shorter.

I didn't knew this way, interesting, thanks! In case of single-assignment (like here) I will stick to using const over this though. In the end I hope typescript will implement this feature and I should make a feature-request.
